# Apply math expressions to xml padding in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

the bottom part of my scroll view was being cut off by the bottom navigation so I applied paddingBottom=?actionBarSize to the constraint layout nested inside to prevent this.

however, I want to add more padding to the bottom something like paddingBottom=?actionBarSize * 1.5. Is there a way to achieve this?

update: I achieved the desired effect by adding padding to the bottom-most view. however i would like to apply to the containing layout.

Comment: Do you use data binding for this XML?

Comment: I do. should I have a constant somewhere with the size?

Comment: Can you please share your layout?

Comment: Did you try `paddingBottom="@{?actionBarSize * 1.5}"`

Comment: I did try this it does not work